# Cannot Import VPN connection (Error: Key file contains line "client" which is not a key-value pair, group, or comment.)

Tags: vpn, openvpn, kali

When I try to import the VPN file i get the following
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxpYS.png) error

can someone help me please?

Comment: Seems pretty clear from the error message that the "VPN File" is not really one. Contact whoever gave it to you.

Comment: @user535733 I used [Private Internet Access](http://www.privateinternetaccess.com/openvpn/openvpn.zip). Do you know somethings else?

Answer (score 0):

Open the VPN file using an editor (my choice is nano) and uncomment the two lines starting with up and down.

then save the document and trying importing it from the VPN settings.

Comment: Can you explain a little more your answer (by giving command line, or lines to comment for example)? So please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1188972/edit) your answer